# Users Get Access Key and Secret Key Stored to Secrets Manager in Cloud Formation

Tags: aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "Installing CloudAuth Application in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS",
    "Parameters": {
        "secretname": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "A descriptive name that helps you find your secret later"
        },
        "myuser": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "Enter existing user name"
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "myaccesskey": {
            "Type": "AWS::IAM::AccessKey",
            "Properties": {
                "UserName": {
                    "Ref": "myuser"
                }
            }
        },
        "mysecrets": {
            "Type": "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": {
                    "Ref": "secretname"
                },
                "SecretString": "{\"Access_Key\":\"${myaccesskey}\",\"Secret_Key\":\"${myaccesskey.SecretAccessKey}\"}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to pass the Access Key and Secret Key to the secret string of Secrets manager resources.

Instead of using:

> "SecretString":
> "{"Access_Key":"${myaccesskey}","Secret_Key":"${myaccesskey.SecretAccessKey}"}"

Try the following format(Fn::Sub function):

> SecretString: !Sub '{ "access_key": "${AccessKey}",
> "secret_key": "${AccessKey.SecretAccessKey}" }'

I used the YAML format for the stack creation.